# Does named/BIND log startup errors?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Does named log startup errors if so what is the default path?

The Wikipedia page for BIND speak of a configuration file verification tool - does anyone know of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

most daemons log to /var/log/daemon. errors sometimes are also logged to /var/log/messages. you can check this by looking at the syslog configuration file /etc/syslog.conf.

the configcheck util for BIND is named-checkconf. it's a bit tricky, if you run your BIND chrooted.

first start with:

```
named-checkconf
```

to check the zone files also:

```
named-checkconf -z
```

in a chrooted environment try this:

```
named-checkconf -t /var/named -z
```

Answer (score 7):

BIND will write startup errors to `syslog`.

Hence the logs will appear wherever your `syslog.conf` says they should go (typically `/var/log/messages`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd look in the default system log. On my system it's `/var/log/messages` but I bet that's distribution-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

There are two verification tools, one for the configuration file itself, and one for zone files.  In Debian, they are called:

- named-checkconf
- named-checkzone

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of DNS validation tools. NSLint is one such tool, which checks zone files on disk.

I've used [DNS Sleuth](http://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~mj/sleuth/) in the past, which does DNS queries to check your setup. You can use the website or download a copy to use locally.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a configurable log file. By default it can be found at `/etc/named/data/named.run`

You can change it's path and control the severity of the messages at `/etc/named.conf` at this part of the file:

```
logging{
  channel default_debug {
    file "data/named.run";
    severity dynamic;
   };
};
```

With the default settings, the content of the `named.run` file would be similar to what is printed at the `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: all fixed, chief.

Comment: You'll see, you will get plenty of upvotes :)